# Transform a Commande Line Linux to a makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile

Is there anyone who can help me to transform this command line to a makefile :

> gcc -o hello_ps hello_ps.c -DMODELDIR=\"pkg-config --variable=modeldir pocketsphinx\" pkg-config --cflags --libs pocketsphinx sphinxbase

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a dependency between the source and the executable you can have :

```
hello_ps: hello_ps.c
    gcc -o hello_ps hello_ps.c -DMODELDIR=\"pkg-config --variable=modeldir pocketsphinx\" pkg-config --cflags --libs pocketsphinx sphinxbase
```

warning there is a <kbd>tab</kbd> before *gcc*, not spaces

Example (I do not have the environment to compile with these options) :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo "whatever I do not compile" > hello_ps.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ make -n
gcc -o hello_ps hello_ps.c -DMODELDIR=\"pkg-config --variable=modeldir pocketsphinx\" pkg-config --cflags --libs pocketsphinx sphinxbase
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ touch hello_ps
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ make -n
make: « hello_ps » is up to date.
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ touch hello_ps.c 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ make -n
gcc -o hello_ps hello_ps.c -DMODELDIR=\"pkg-config --variable=modeldir pocketsphinx\" pkg-config --cflags --libs pocketsphinx sphinxbase
```

Of course you can add more dependencies, with included header file(s), with libs etc.